# Looking for a fantasy book about ape-like humans who get invaded by humans

Tags: story-identification, books

This is a book I read when I was in high school. The main story revolves around these ape-like humanoids, who are the main characters, that get invaded by humans and later enslaved.  It was a softcover book and the cover had these ape-like human hybrids hiding by a big tree from the invading humans.

I am not sure about whether they can use magic or not, but it's more or less how the main characters overcome the invasion. Later on, some of the humans realize what they are doing is bad and join forces with the ape-like humanoids.

Answer (score 6):

Ursula K. Le Guin's "[The Word for World Is Forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Word_for_World_is_Forest)" ?  (Another synopsis [here](http://hem.passagen.se/peson42/lgw/books/b_forest.html)).

Answer (score 4):

Was the novel [A Different Flesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Different_Flesh)? The ape-like humanoids (known as "sims") are not as intelligent as normal humans, and the novel contains several vignettes about the social changes that come about due to having something similar but not exactly at human intelligence.

Sims are eventually enslaved, and this ends up leading to (human) emancipation much earlier than in the real timeline. There were also human-sim hybrids later in the book.

The cover (you can see it on Wikipedia) is of a humanish face and a tree, which is somewhat similar to your recollection.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but its not the book.  This book was fictional/fantasy.  The main characters are the ape like humanoids while the normal humans invade them and enslave them.  I am not sure about if they can use magic or not but its more or less how the main characters overcome the invasion.  Later on some of the humans realize this is bad and join forces with the ape like humanoids.

Comment: @user14042: You should put any extra details you remember like that in the original question!

Answer (score 3):

Could it possibly be 1952's *[Les Animaux dénaturés](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Animaux_d%C3%A9natur%C3%A9s)*?  The 1970 Burt Reynolds' film *[Skullduggery](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066384/)* is based on that novel and, according to IMDb, the plot is as follows:

> An expedition into the interior of Papua New Guinea comes across a
>   tribe of ape-like people who may or may not be ancestors of early man.
>   However, the influence of modern man is to have devastating effects
>   upon these forgotten people.

Answer (score 2):

*[The Ancient Enemy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/366412.Ancient_Enemy)* - The First [Book of Arna](http://www.christopherrowley.net/novels/ArnaSeries.php) by Christopher Rowley.

[image: Book Cover]

> Young watermot Thru Gillo left behind the life of a farmer and became a student of the Assenzi, a race of scholars. Among them, he learned the history of his race and of how Man the Cruel destroyed the world before disappearing into the mists of time and legend.Or have they disappeared..?

If its the one I was just looking for..the ape like people are called Mots and Mors..the main character is a weaver of decorative grass mats.

Comment: Could you add any details about this work?

Comment: Might try looking at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126247/title-of-a-fantasy-novel-about-ape-like-humanoids-that-are-invaded-by-humans?rq=1; has a similar question & answer, but not accepted